# Nuxt.js и определение координат внутри страницы сайта

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, es2016

Есть такая задача:

Например у меня на странице есть хедер(шапка сайта) которую я хотел бы 
показывать только при прокрутке страницы вниз на какое то кол-во пикселей.

Вопрос:
Есть ли в Vue.js для этого какие то дополнительные инструменты?
Если нет то что можно почитать по чистому js для того что бы реализовать данную задачу?

Иными словами если перефразировать - как лучше всего измерять точку отсчета от начала страницы или же от какого то елемента и какие есть для этого инструменты?
(в VUE.js или может в NUXT.js что то дополнительно придумали.)

Comment: https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/creating-custom-scroll-directives.html
читайте всё, внимательно и до конца.

Comment: C подключением вроде разобрался - но почему то в браузерах ie не работает директива.

Comment: http://joxi.ru/BA0QjX0IJeG5Wr
вот эти елементы во всех браузерах работают во время прокрутки вниз страницы - а в ie(как минимум 9,10) вообще нет никакой реакции.
http://webmaster.ayrveda.ru/perfect_goods/
 в чем может быть причина?